# Webdriver not identifying iframes

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to find and switch to iframe. Although, I can see it in HTML, my code cannot find it.  I have Multiple iframes and I need to navigate to the child. However, my code cannot seem to find the parent iframe.

Here is what I have-

```
driver.switchTo().frame("mc-app-iframe");
```

and

```
<div class="mc-canvas" role="main">
<div id="59fa" class="mc-canvas" style="display: block;">
<div class="mc-app">
<iframe class="mc-app-iframe" seamless="seamless" name="canvas-b2ca1f50-3cc4-4fd7-a3a3-88bf09fb59fa" style="min-width: 0px;" src="https://t1.com/C12/Default.aspx?entityType=none&entityID=0&hub=1&context=35d50b059#Subscribers" frameborder="0">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To switch to the frame you need to provide either the frame name or frame id. In your case we will take help of the frame name as below:

`driver.switchTo().frame("canvas-b2ca1f50-3cc4-4fd7-a3a3-88bf09fb59fa");`

Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
WebElement iFrame= driver.findElement(By.tagName("iframe")); 
// can alternatively use css selector "iframe.mc-app-iframe"
driver.switchTo().frame(iFrame);
```

Hope this helps